# ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pip

As I have seen many posts with solutions for the problems on installing Tensorflow, I still can't get it to work. I tried following lines:

> `pip install --upgrade tensorflow`

Result:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> tensorflow (from versions: none)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow

I also tried:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow_cpu-2.2.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
```

with this result:

> ERROR: tensorflow_cpu-2.2.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

I installed Python 3.9, 64 bit:

> Python 3.9.0 (tags/v3.9.0:9cf6752, Oct  5 2020, 15:34:40) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

The only thing that is different from all other posts that I could find is that the version information of Python says:

> ... 64 bit (AMD64)] **on win32**

but I have installed a native 64 bit Windows 10 Pro installation:
[Version Info Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apzVu.jpg)

To be complete I am using pip version 20.2.3

So what could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

While reviewing my post I noticed that the TensorFlow package is for Python version 3.8 and my Python version was 3.9. Downgrading to 3.8.6 solved the problem.